# Delay on using fn key programs

Tags: windows-7, function-keys, delayed-execution

For some reason, even when my computer is not doing anything (CPU usage is about 10% ish) using my function key programs (calculator, backlight, volume etc) take about 3 seconds to go through. No other programs have this issue when I try to start them up.

My computer is an Asus G60 series, all drivers are up to date, and this is a fairly recent (last week or two) problem.

Is there an obvious reason why this should be?

Sorry I don't have better documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps to know what kind of computer you have.  I can take a guess why though.  Usually it's a background program that controls the on screen display of these things.

If it is a driver, then it could be some weird conflict.  Drivers are notoriously difficult to write, let alone write well.

Best bet is to check your drivers and make sure to get any updates from Microsoft too.  Also google your laptop model.  These problems are impressively difficult to nail down.

Comment: Edited my question to include the laptop model